# Progress bar is not showing in Mercurial Version Control in Push or Pull

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have the `.hgrc` file for mercurial like this

```
[paths]
default = XXXX
[ui]
username = XXXX
[hostfingerprints]
bitbucket.org = 24:9C:45:8B:9C:AA:BA:55:4E:01:6D:58:FF:E4:28:7D:2A:14:AB:3C
[extensions]
# shows progress bar for certain tasks
progress=
```

I have enabled the extension for progress but here I can't see the progress bar when I am doing anything `Push` or `Pull`.

Answer (score 1):

Progress bars are shown after  delay of 3 seconds by default. You can change this by adding

```
[progress]
delay = 1.5
```

to your hgrc file. Check Manual: `hg help progress`